# C++ Xtensor increase floating point significant numbers

Tags: c++, xtensor

I am building a neural network and using xtensor for array multiplication in feed forward. The network takes in `xt::xarray<double>` and outputs a decimal number between 0 and 1. I have been given a sheet for expected output. when i compare my output with the provided sheet, I found that all the results differ after exactly 7 digits. for example if the required value is `0.1234567890123456`, I am getting values like `0.1234567-garbage-numbers-so-that-total-numbers-equal-16`, `0.1234567993344660`, `0.1234567221155667`.

I know I can not get that exact number `0.1234567890123456` due to floating point math. But how can I debug/ increase precision to be close to that required number. thanks

Update:

```
    xt::xarray<double> Layer::call(xt::xarray<double> input)
    {
        return xt::linalg::dot(input, this->weight) + this->bias;
    }
```

for code I am simply calling this `call` method a bunch of times where `weight` and `bias` are `xt::xarray<double>` arrays.

Comment: Show your code, especially the part that is outputting the values.  Your output function may be the culprit, not your arithmetic.

Comment: added the code sir. I don't know but a simple answer can be that xtensor does provide precision numbers upto 15 or 16 decimal digits or even more and somehow there is a good chance that my code is not working and people never had this issue with xtensor before.

Comment: As far as I know `xt::linalg::dot` just wraps LAPACK/BLAS, as is probably the case for whatever problem generated the reference output.